# Dojo JsonRest Promise -- order of asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dojo, promise

Running dojo 1.8.4

Using a JsonRest (not a JsonRestStore), I make a put request to an end point, and get the result back and gather location information from the request response, like so:

```
var promise = myJsonRest.put(data).then(function(){
    // act when put completes successfully
    promise.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader('location');
});
```

Until recently, this worked without a problem. Then I started seeing a TypeError where the promise no longer contained ioArgs (cannot read property xhr of undefined).

Breakpoints and stepping through the stack indicated that ioArgs was being created and returned, but that the promise it fulfilled was not my `then(function () { promise.ioArgs /* etc... */ });`

The solution that I found was to change my above code to this...

```
var promise = myJsonRest.put(data);
promise.then(function(){
    // act when put completes successfully
    promise.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader('location');
});
```

...which works correctly, but I can't justify why.

It cannot be that the promise assigned by `myJsonRest.put()` is not the same as the object evaluated at `myJsonRest.put().then()`.  The only theory I have at this point is that JsonRest, on it's own asynchronous time, is adding promises that fall between the `put()` request and my then handler.  Since ioArgs is not carried across promises, it is lost by the time it gets to my function.  Assigning my behavior (`then()`) to the promise the line after the promise is fired must put my behavior first on the stack of promises to be resolved.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It cannot be that the promise assigned by `myJsonRest.put()` is not the same as the object evaluated at `myJsonRest.put().then()`.

It is the same object for the `myJsonRest.put()` part, no worries. Your problem is that in the first snippet you're assigning the result of the `.then()` method call to `promise`, and that does return a different promise (see [the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/promise/Promise#then)).

Compare

```
var promise;
( promise = myJsonRest.put(data).then(function(){…}) );
```

to

```
var promise;
( promise = myJsonRest.put(data) ).then(function(){…});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to  `.then()` needs to return the value you want `promise` resolved with:

```
var promise = myJsonRest.put(data).then(function(response){
    // act when put completes successfully
    // do stuff with the response from the put request
    return response;
});
```